# Order results with the combination of first name, last name in rails controller

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I want to order the result of the query by the combination of first name and last name.

User model have index defined as

```
define_index do
  indexes :first_name
  indexes :last_name

  has first_name, :as => :fname
  has last_name, :as => :lname
end
```

In my controller's action i am retrieving results like this.

```
 @results = User.search(query,
                                :with => options,
                                :order => "fname ASC",                                
                                :match_mode => :extended).page(params[:page]).per(11)
```

It order results by first_name and results are like this.

```
              Micheal Clark
              Niel Johnson
              Micheal Beaven
```

But i want to order the results by the combination of first_name and last name.
Something like this should be returned.

```
              Micheal Beaven
              Micheal Clark                  
              Niel Johnson
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Shouldn't the order be `Michael Beaven` -> `Michael Clark` -> `Niel Johnson` in the first case? (`N` comes after `M`.)

Comment: sorry, i changed order now. Check it again plz :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
has last_name, :as => :fname
```

To

```
has first_name, :as => :fname
```

Following should work

```
:order => "first_name, last_name",
```

Comment: It was a typo in writing question. Please read question again give me an appropriate suggestion.